# Changing the user after sudo - command over ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo

Im accessing my sever over SSH, with a normal user account. At some point i need to log as root, i have the root and password credentials, but when I invoke the `sudo -` command the prompt ask me for a root password for the current logged user user, how can i change the username back to root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing two commands: `sudo` and `su`.

`sudo` allows you to run a single command as another user.

`su` allows you to switch to another user.

So, when you've signed in as your normal user, if you want to issue a single command as root, you should use sudo:

```
$ sudo <command>
```

This will ask for **your** password.

Likewise, if you want to issue a command as user `jimbob`:

```
$ sudo -u jimbob <command>
```

This will also ask for **your** password.

If you want to switch to the root user:

```
$ su -
```

This will ask for the **root** password.

It is **highly** recommended that you always use `sudo` to run privileged commands, though, instead of switching to another user.